# Error with capifony deployment to FreeBSD system

Tags: symfony, deployment, capistrano, freebsd, capifony

I have a problem with uploading code to FreeBSD server.

Deployment output:

```
--> Updating code base with checkout strategy
Password for user@server: 
--> Creating cache directory................................✔
--> Creating symlinks for shared directories................✔
--> Creating symlinks for shared files......................✔
--> Normalizing asset timestamps............................✔
--> Copying vendors from previous release...................✔
--> Downloading Composer....................................✘
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
failed: "sh -c 'sh -c '\\''cd /var/www/domain.com/releases/20140215073342 && curl -s http://getcomposer.org/installer | php'\\'''" on 0.0.0.0
```

And if i run the code:

```
sh -c 'sh -c '\\''cd /var/www/domain.com/releases/20140215073342 && curl -s http://getcomposer.org/installer | php'\\'''
```

on server, i have a error:

```
-bash: php\\: command not found
```

Can this error in freebsd system with escape special chars?

Thank.

**UPD**

PHP Cli installed (Version: 5.5.9)

Comment: Can you on server run php from console, for example php -v ?

Comment: PHP-cli installed (Version: 5.5.9)

Answer (score 3):

It seems that now you can not download composer using HTTP, only HTTPS. Capifony has hardcoded installation command for composer which uses HTTP, and does not follow redirects.

With other words it's a bug in Capifony, and it seems that there is no workaround to fix it using configuration.

Comment: Actually in my case error occurred in the next step after `Downloading Composer`, so I think you have different problem.

Comment: Yes, but this change applies 3 days ago.

Answer (score -2):

I know the answer is a late but I was with the same issue and I can fix it enabling the extension `phar` in my server. I had this message when I tried to install composer manually .

> Install it or recompile php without --disable-phar

Comment: I was working with a Synology DS214, and getting this issue, but when I have enabled the option "phar" in "control panel -> web services ->php settings -> php extensions" .  the issue was fixed for me.